# Git rebase gives conflicts on remote branch, but works on local

Tags: git

I have 2 branches - `develop` and `master`, I added new commits to both of them and now I want to rebase `develop` on top of `master`.

When I do

```
git checkout develop
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

it gives me tons of conflicts, which I can barely explain, but if I do

```
git checkout master
git pull origin HEAD
git checkout develop
git rebase master
```

it does a correct rebase without any conflicts.

Can someone explain me what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: There's not enough info here to help you. But `origin/master` and `master` might not be on the same commit. You can verify what commit each one is on with `git show master` and `git show origin/master`. `master` is what your local branch is on. `origin/master` is the behind the scenes branch information, the latest information git has locally about the "remote" repository arbitrarily named "origin" (the git default).

Comment: As a random aside, not related to your question, the "git flow" pattern, with a develop and a main branch, is a terrible pattern that no one does anymore. I'm not sure if you're using git flow, but it offers no benefits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible points:

- an (important) effect of `git pull` is to *merge the changes in your local branch with the pulled branch*, the result is a different commit,
- you rebased on top of `origin/master` but pulled `HEAD` ; if the default branch for your remote is *not* master (e.g: for a `github` repo, the default branch is now named `main`) then the result can be different

---

Run `git log --oneline --graph HEAD master origin/master` in a terminal (that or open a graphical viewer for the history of your repo, and check the 3 branches `HEAD master origin/master`), you will have a better view of what is included and what isn't

Comment: That was the case for us - we've been using detached head, surprisingly, on two different envirenments, thanks!

Comment: @Majesty make sure that your Bash prompt shows the git branch name in the prompt. There's no point in using Git without that set up in Bash.

Comment: @AndyRay point taken, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to always perform a `git pull` on the branch before starting any kind of merge or rebase operation. This ensures that your local branch is up-to-date with the remote branch, and there are no conflicts due to changes made by others in the meantime.

When you did `git fetch` followed by `git rebase origin/master` on the develop branch, it fetched the latest changes from the remote master branch but didn't apply those changes to your local master branch. So when you tried to rebase develop on top of origin/master, it had to resolve conflicts that arose due to the differences between your local master branch and the remote master branch.

On the other hand, when you did `git pull` origin HEAD on the master branch, it updated your local master branch with the latest changes from the remote master branch. So when you then did `git checkout develop` followed by `git rebase master`, it was able to cleanly apply the changes made on the master branch to the develop branch without any conflicts.

In summary, it's always a good practice to pull the latest changes from the remote branch before starting any rebase or merge operations.

Comment: This is not correct, @PraveenKumar. Working against the remote branch is OK and actually _avoids_ having to deal with the local branch (in case you have it... I for one do not keep local equivalents of remote branches like `master`, `main`, etc... I work against the remote branch).